# celery parallel tasking error 'no result backend configured'

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

Running django-celery 3.1.16, Celery 3.1.17, Django 1.4.16. Trying to run some parallel tasks using 3 workers and collect the results using the following:

```
from celery import group

positions = []
jobs = group(celery_calculate_something.s(data.id) for data in a_very_big_list)
results = jobs.apply_async()
positions.extend(results.get())
```

The task celery_calculate_something returns an object to place the in the results list:

```
app.task(ignore_result=False)
def celery_calculate_something(id):
  <do stuff>
```

No matter what I try, I always get the same result when calling get() on results:

```
No result backend configured.  Please see the documentation for more information.
```

However, the results backend IS configured - I have many other tasks with ignore_result=False merrily adding to the tasks meta table in django_celery. It is something to do with using the results returned from group(). I should note it is not set explicitly in settings - it seems that django-celery has set it automatically for you.

I have the worker collecting events using:

```
manage.py celery worker -l info -E
```

and celerycam running with

```
python manage.py celerycam
```

Inspecting the results object returned (an instance of GroupResult) I can see that the backend attr is an instance of DisabledBackend. Is this the problem? What have I mis-understood?

Answer (score 0):

You did not configure the results backend, so basically you need tables to store the results, since you have **django-celery** add it to **INSTALLED_APPS** in your ***settings.py*** file and then perform the migration (`python manage.py migrate`) After that open your ***celery.py*** file and modify your backend to **djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend**. 
 Here's an example

```
app = Celery('almanet',
 broker='amqp://guest@localhost//',
 backend='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend',
 include=['alm_crm.tasks'] #References your tasks. Donc forget to put the whole absolute path.
 )
```

After that you can import results `from celery import result` Now you can save the result and extract the result by job.id

```
from celery import group
positions = []
jobs = group(celery_calculate_something.s(data.id) for data in
a_very_big_list)
results = jobs.apply_async()
results.save()
some_task_result = result.GroupResult.restore(results.id)
print some_task_results.ready()
```